# Fetch RowID from Sqlite in IOS

Tags: ios, sqlite

I am using SQLITE in one of my ios application.

I need to fetch the rowID for all the records.
Example:-
There are 6 rows in my table.
If i delete 4th row than the ID_Column(maintain by the me) have sequence.
1,2,3,5,6
But i want is 1,2,3,4,5.

So is there any way to fetch the rowid for selected row?

For example:- `Select rowid from TableName where projectName='ABC'`

Can we do that?

I had search and found that we can do like this :-

```
 NSInteger lastInsertedID = sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(database);

 NSInteger rowsUpdated = sqlite3_total_changes(database);
```

IS there any way to get row id of the selected row?

Comment: What do you think you need the consecutive rowids for? Can't you just count the records when you call `sqlite3_step`?

Comment: Depending on the size of the database, and whether it is on the client or server, it is common to have a column that toggles whether the row is accessible or not. For instance, you could put a `isDeleted` field. The reason is that even though the data is "deleted" from the users perspective, maybe other data that you will use still needs it. Also, like CL asked, what benefit do you plan on gaining by having the ID_Column always in order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableName AS tempTable2 WHERE tempTable2.ID_Column >= tempTable1. ID_Column) AS Row_Number, id, name FROM TableName tempTable1 ORDER BY Row_Number ASC
```

Here you are creating a temporary table with existing table, which contains an extra field called `Row_Number`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you need the rowid (you could simply count the records), but you could use [VACUUM](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html) to rebuild the database. [This article](http://www.sqlabs.com/blog/2010/12/sqlite-and-unique-rowid-something-you-really-need-to-know/) may also be useful and provide additional information on why you should be careful when relying on rowids.